# throw new ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE(originalStatusCode);

Tags: node.js, express, session

Here is my code, I want to render a number on the website and it can be added at once I reload the page. And I have the problem above. Please tell me what I need to add or delete, thanks.

```
const express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
    secret: 'HelloExpressSESSION',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.get('/mysession', function(req, res) {

    if (req.session.count) {
        req.session.count++;
    } else {
        req.session.count = 1;
    }

    res.sendStatus(req.session.count);
    res.end();
});
app.listen(12345);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the people who answer my question!

I change

```
res.sendStatus(req.session.count);
```

to

```
res.send(`${req.session.count}`);
```

,then it works XD.

Post and share it with the people who also have the same problem.